# Syncfusion XlsIO: Trying to insert list of images from folder into each row. Same image showing

Tags: excel, console-application, .net-6.0, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion XlsIO in a .NET 6 Console Application to insert data into a sheet including an image on the end of each row. I am following the official documentation [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/working-with-pictures?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp).

There are no errors but when I open the file file after the application completes I see the same image being inserted into every row. I have stepped through the loop and I can see the image object changing. Below is the code I am using:

```
int row = 1;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in imgTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataRow.ToString());
    string imagePath = $"./tempImages/{dataRow.ItemArray[1]}";

    using (FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        IPictureShape shape = alarmWorksheet.Pictures.AddPicture(row, 4, imageStream);
        imgWorksheet.SetRowHeight(row, 288);
    }

    row++;
}
```

I have also tried this because there is an overload for the Image type.

```
int row = 1;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in imgTable.Rows)
{
    alarmWorksheet.SetRowHeight(row, 216);
    Console.WriteLine(dataRow.ToString());
    string imagePath = $"./tempImages/{dataRow.ItemArray[1]}";

    using (FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        Image img = new Image(imageStream);
        imgWorksheet.Pictures.AddPicture(row, 4, img);
    }

    row++;
}
```

Comment: I coincidentally ran into the same issue just now. I downgraded all the way to 21.1.10 and the behavior seems consistent... so if you find a solution I'd be happy to hear about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This was a bug since version 20.0.4.54 that got resolved in version 23.1.40.

---

*Original answer including chronological updates:*

I had the same issue while upgrading some old code.

I seems like you need to keep `Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core` at or below version 20.0.4.54 seems to work. I realize this is not a permanent solution but perhaps you can live with it for now.

I've reported this as a bug to Syncfusion, perhaps you can do the same.

[Update 1] I just got a reply from Syncfusion support that they are looking at my report and will update shortly. I figured I will update this answer with the progress.

[Update 2] Syncfusion said they "have fixed a similar issue in our recent version of XlsIO. We request you upgrade to the latest NuGet version 23.1.40 and check whether the issue is resolved." I don't have time to test that now, but I'll do that shortly.

[Update 3] Final update: The latest version fixes the issue for me, also see the official [answer by Syncfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287851/2920343).

Comment: Thank you @CompuChip. That was exactly it. I dropped below that version and it worked right away. Thanks again

Comment: @psycho I'm updating the post as I get feedback from Syncfusion support. They just told me: We have fixed a similar issue in our recent version of XlsIO. We request you upgrade to the latest NuGet version 23.1.40 and check whether the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already fixed by Syncfusion XlsIO and the fix is included in the latest v23.1.40 NuGet package.

NuGet : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core

Comment: Thanks, the latest release fixes the issue (this also closes your ticket #510171).